# Blender 2.82 video editor stopped rendering mov video files

Tags: rendering, video-sequence-editor, video

I have been working on a music video using an mp3 track and both mov and mp4 video clips.

About half way through the project, and after I already rendered parts of the video successfully, I tried to render my nearly completed video and the output was a black screen.
After looking into each clip individually I found out that it is only the mov files that wont render and the sound and mp4 files work fine.

It definitely feels like I changed some setting by accident because the error started mid project.

Comment: Try to isolate the issue, eg create a new project using just that mkv: does it work? or not anymore?

Comment: i wrote mkv earlier but its actually mov files that wont work. when i open them on a new blender file they work fine.